# How to set a fixed or minimum audio bit rate over a bluetooth device using iPhone?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, connectivity, bitrate

I am totally new into this bluetooth side, if anyone can help me or provide over links for further information could be really helpful.

I am trying to create a seamless high quality bit rate transfer of audio from iPhone to a third party bluetooth device (i.e a headphone). 
Generally, from iPhone the audio will be compressed encoded and transfer for fast connectivity to a bluetooth device, but the audio quality will decrease. 
I am finding ways to change the codec used and to have a better bit rate so the audio listening on the bluetooth is of good quality for both listening and recording.

Comment: I don't believe you have any control over how audio is delivered to an external device

Answer (score 0):

You can use AudioUnit in iOS and change the sample rate using AudioStreamBasicDescription

```
AudioStreamBasicDescription audioDescription = {0};
audioDescription.mFormatID          = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
audioDescription.mFormatFlags       = kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked | kAudioFormatFlagsNativeEndian;
audioDescription.mChannelsPerFrame  = 1;
audioDescription.mBytesPerPacket    = sizeof(SInt16)*audioDescription.mChannelsPerFrame;
audioDescription.mFramesPerPacket   = 1;
audioDescription.mBytesPerFrame     = sizeof(SInt16)*audioDescription.mChannelsPerFrame;
audioDescription.mBitsPerChannel    = 8 * sizeof(SInt16);
audioDescription.mSampleRate        = 8000.0;
```

And you can change the preferred sample rate of your app:

```
let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
let bufferDuration :NSTimeInterval = 0.005
try session.setPreferredIOBufferDuration(bufferDuration)
try session.setPreferredSampleRate(8000.0)
try session.setActive(true)
```

Comment: Please note that the actual sample rate may be different once the AVAudioSession has been activated.